# How does Shield Dancer's ability work with a creature that has Trample?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a [Shield Dancer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShield%20Dancer%5d), 1/3, whose activated ability states:

> The next time target attacking creature would deal combat damage to Shield Dancer this turn, that creature deals that damage to itself instead.

He blocks a 6/1 creature with Trample, such as [Ball Lightning](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBall%20Lightning%5d). Trample states that leftover damage carries over to the 'defending' player. With the Shield Dancer's ability activated and the damage reversed, what happens with the left over trample damage?

Answer (score 19):

**The attacking Ball Lightning would deal 3-6 damage to itself and the rest to the defending player.**

Assigning combat damage and actually dealing combat damage are two different actions during the combat damage step:

> 510.1. First, the active player announces how each attacking creature assigns its combat damage [..]
>
> 510.2. Second, all combat damage that’s been assigned is dealt simultaneously [..]

Shield dancer's ability modifies how damage is dealt, but the rules for assigning combat damage from an attacking creature with trample remain the same:

> 702.19b The controller of an attacking creature with trample first assigns damage to the creature(s) blocking it. Once all those blocking creatures are assigned lethal damage, any remaining damage is assigned as its controller chooses among those blocking creatures and the player or planeswalker the creature is attacking. [..]

When determining what constitutes lethal damage, the Shield Dancer's ability is not taken into account. 702.19b continues:

> 702.19b [..] When checking for assigned lethal damage, take into account damage already marked on the creature and damage from other creatures that’s being assigned during the same combat damage step, **but not any abilities or effects that might change the amount of damage that’s actually dealt.** The attacking creature’s controller need not assign lethal damage to all those blocking creatures but in that case can’t assign any damage to the player or planeswalker it’s attacking.

Therefore, the attacking player has to assign at least 3 and at most all 6 points of damage to the Shield Dancer, so it would receive lethal damage. The rest is assigned to the defending player. Then when the damage is actually dealt, the Shield Dancer's replacement effect happens, the damage assigned to the Shield Dancer is dealt to the Ball Lightning instead, and the damage assigned to the defending player is dealt to that player.

Comment: Does this also mean that a 6/6 creature with Trample would be able to survive the reflected damage? That's not what I'd intuitively expect reading the ability, perhaps it's worth pointing out explicitly?

Comment: What do you expect when you read the ability, what is unclear about it?

Comment: I would expect that the redirect effect happens before assigning the amount of damage, so you'd have to assign 1 to the Ball Lightning and trample 5, and would have to assign 6 to a 6/6 trample blocker.

Comment: I see. So I take it my answer does not clear that up for you? In particular the part where I separate damage assignment and damage dealing, and how the Shield Dancer only affects damage dealing.

Comment: @Erik that's what makes intuitive sense, perhaps, but it's not the way redirection works in magic - redirection like this only affects the damage when it's being dealt, but not when it's being assigned, so a 6/6 with trample would survive, but a 6/6 without trample would not.

Comment: I have added a bit about what constitutes lethal damage and that Shield Dancer's ability does not force the attacker to assign 6 damage to the Shield Dancer if it only has 3 toughness.

Comment: @Andrew I think you meant 6/1 in the second part, to late to edit so figured I would clarify

Comment: @Hackworth The same rulings would affect prevention like when a creature has protection and blocks a trample creature right? I know from experience it works this way but not what comprehensive rules are associated with it. If so it might be worth mentioning that this works the same way as prevention of damage.

Comment: @Erik This gets even more interesting when ball lightning has trample and death touch because death touch means you only have to assign one damage for lethal damage so he would trample over for 5 against your creature no matter how much toughness it had and you would redirect 1 damage to it.

Comment: @MaxYoung Correct, if the defending creature has protection or any other damage prevention/reduction, the attacker still only has to assign as much damage as the creature has toughness, the rest can go to the defending player.

Comment: @MaxYoung I doubted this when you first mentioned it, but it turns out this is true, per rule 702.2c:  "Any nonzero amount of combat damage assigned to a creature by a source with deathtouch is considered to be lethal damage for the purposes of determining if a proposed combat damage assignment is valid, regardless of that creature’s toughness."

Comment: @BradC I only know this because I watched a friend taking lessons from a judge. The judge had built packs of cards that he put in sleeves. The front of the sleeve contained a note card that said what the scenario was and the judge had organized them together by difficulty. I didn't know what comprehensive rule dictated it but figured it would be interesting for the purposes of this question because it shows the difference between damage assignment and damage dealt which the OP was struggling with. So in this case lethal damage must be assigned first but lethal damage is not always toughness.

Comment: @MaxYoung i did not, a 6/6 without trample would assign 6 damage to shield dancer and have all 6 redirected, which is enough to kill itself. A 6/1 would die with or without trample.

Comment: @Andrew I reread your comment I see what you meant now, sorry about that. I am leaving my old post for context.